# Matlab calling fvtool from freqz, if DFILT object is passed

Tags: matlab, signals, toolbox

Hello my fellow signal processors! :-D

the following thing has been driving me crazy. Consider the documentation of the `freqz` command at [the mathworks homepage.](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/toolbox/signal/ref/freqz.html)

If the `freqz` command is passed an FIR filter vector containing the coefficients, it creates a plot as in [this image.](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/toolbox/signal/ref/freqz_example.png) If it is passed a DFILT object, e.g. an IIR filter, it creates a plot like the second image on the mathworks help page. (i.e., phase and magnitude both in one plot)

How can I make `freqz` create a plot like in the first image, while passing it a DFILT object?

Thank you very much.

(Sorry - I can't post images or more than two hyperlinks.)

Comment: You might get better answers to this on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/?as=1 where your fellow signal processors might be found.